# Why does an Opera widget (analog clock) use so much CPU?

Tags: 10.10, performance, opera

When I was using Arch Linux with KDE 4.5 and Opera analogue clock widget, it was much less CPU-consuming. Now, on Ubuntu 10.10 (and I use the same proper graphics driver) it consumes mean of 15% of CPU (least of 11%, max of 34%). What may the reason be?

Answer (score 3):

maybe a bug in drivers or kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 is in beta. Have you tried reporting this as a bug? Also, what means are you using to record the cpu usage? Some programs have overhead or report it incorrectly. (Not that I do not believe you).

Also reasons may be an obscure bug for your graphics hardware, perhaps due to something in the xorg stack. If it uses OpenGL, perhaps it now is only using software rendering due to an incompatibility. Etc..

Comment: "Ubuntu 10.10 is in beta. Have you tried reporting this as a bug?" - I pretty much believe they'll close it saying "report the bug to Opera", and maybe they'll be right, but the situation is that it does not behave any close to so ugly in Arch. And I have a pretty ancient built-in Intel graphics card. I've asked in hope someone may know a workaround.